# Get first image from last post in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Can't get the first picture in the last post (function - get_first_post_image). Where is the mistake? Please help me. Thank you in advance for your help.

```
function get_first_post_image() {
    global $post, $posts;
    $first_img = '';

    ob_start();
    ob_end_clean();

    if(preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post->post_content, $matches)){
        $first_img = $matches [1] [0];
        return $first_img;
    }
    else {
        $first_img = "http://yyyyyy/post-default.png";
        return $first_img;
    }
};
    
function custom_function(){
    $args = array( 
        'numberposts' => '1', 
    );

    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );

    foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ):
        $post_id        = $recent['ID'];
        $post_url       = get_permalink($recent['ID']);
        $post_title     = $recent['post_title'];
        $post_content   = $recent['post_content'];
        $post_thumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail($recent['ID']);
        $imglink        = get_first_post_image($recent['ID']);
    endforeach;
    
    $data = '... ' . $imglink . ' ...';
    
    ....
    
}
```

Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've rewritten the function to return the default image if no first image is found. Best way of parsing HTML is DOM parsing, not regex.

```
function get_first_post_image(string $post_content): string
{
    $defaultImage = 'http://yyyyyy/post-default.png';

    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML($post_content);

    $img = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
    if (!$img->length) return $defaultImage;

    return $img->item(0)->getAttribute('src') ?: $defaultImage;
}
```

You are calling `get_first_post_image()` with the ID instead of the post content.

change

```
$imglink = get_first_post_image($recent['ID']);
```

to

```
$imglink = get_first_post_image($recent['post_content']);
```

I've updated the function above

- Changed Signature
- Removed `global $post`
- Changed `loadHtml()`

Comment: Return post-default.png :-(

Comment: If that happens, then `$post->post_content` does not contain an image tag. Can you dump it to debug?

Comment: I've found the error. See my answer updated (code changed!!)

Comment: Thanks. Works :-)